# How to multiply outputs of the neurons in a layer? (preferably in Keras or Tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Consider I have a dense layer and I want to multiply the outputs of the units in my next layer:

```
dense_layer = Dense(n_unit)(input_layer)
next_layer = {Multiply outputs of the n_unit in the dense layer}
```

Is there any simple way to achieve this functionality?
If no, is it even possible to define a new layer with this aim or there is a fundamental limitation?

Comment: `dense_layer` is a tensor of any shape say a vector (1D array). And you want to multiply it's elements?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Can I use lambda layers here? I'm a bit new to Keras :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a lambda layer, and `tf.reduce_prod(dense_layer)` function.

For example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
dense_layer = [1,2,3,4,5]
next_layer = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.reduce_prod(x))(dense_layer)
print(next_layer)  # <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=120>
```